# Best Way to Store Previously Entered User Input in EditText?

Tags: android

What is the best way to store previously entered user input from an EditText and have that EditText suggest it back to the user when they begin to type it the next time they use the application?

My original idea was to use an AutoCompleteTextView which would then store user inputed data into an array (maybe using SharedPreferences?).  Upon application reload, it would pull up this string array and be available to suggest previously entered input the user.  Obviously SharedPreferences can't store arrays, so what is the best way to go about doing this?

I can't seem to find this question posted elsewhere.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store arrays in shared preferences.  Truth be told, you can store objects in them too ;)

I store the data in a comma delimited string then get it out with this:

```
String [] tth_array = TextUtils.split(appPrefs.getTransmissionTimeHistory(), ",");
```

Comment: +1, arrays are supported. And if you don't like them ;-), you can still use a text delimited and put everything in one string and into the sharedPres, although no need for that.